# Unable to install m2crypto due to poll.h missing error

Tags: python, pip, m2crypto

I've taken these steps while trying to get m2crypto to install for python 2.7.9 on Windows:

1. Download swig and add the swig directory to my 'Path' Environment Variable
2. Download openssl and copy the lib and include directories from my openssl directory to C:/pkg/
3. Install Visual C++ 9.0
4. pip install m2crypto

That results in this error:

```
SWIG/_m2crypto_wrap.c(6319) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'poll.h': No such file or directory
error: command 'C:\\Users\\brad.leary\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Common\\Microsoft\\Visual C++ for Python\\9.0\\VC\\Bin\\amd64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
```

I've repeated this process on 2 separate windows machines and found the same result, so I'm surprised that I can't find more people online having the same issue.